# unicode character set in Oracle SQL

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, unicode, type-conversion

I have a C# service that currently reads info from the database (Oracle 11) inserted by a 3rd party application.

The 3rd party application is generating the code from XML, and is saving the information in unicode.

The C# application reads the text using the following method:

```
public static String GetUnicodeString(Byte[] bytes)
{
    return UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

The text in the database has the hex 00 in between each character. Example:

> Considering the string: Test
>
> Non UNICODE Hex values: 54 65 73 74
>
> UNICODE Hex values in the DB: 54 00 65 00 73 00 74 00

If I loop through the whole string adding the hex 00 works fine, but it doesn't sound the most efficient way, and looks ugly.

How to convert the string to the format currently generated by the 3rd party app (with hex 00 in between characters)?

Here is an example on how the string is rendered in the database (blob column):
[image]

Comment: What is the database column type? Also can you do a `SELECT dump(column) FROM your_table` on the row with your small sample, it would be helpful to determine if the `00` byte is present in the table.

Comment: It is a blob type. In the PL/SQL Developer, I can see the hex 00 listed.

Comment: It must be stored as UTF16 (which uses 2 bytes for each character), not UTF8. CLOBs in Oracle use AL32UTF16. Reading data in this character set should provide a usable string.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat is correct, Encoding.unicode would be utf-16.

Comment: You got it. I just used "AL16UTF16LE", and it converted accordingly. many thanks!